# preg_match() to split a string by another string which is not in apostrophes

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have many strings like this:

```
parameter_1 >= '23' AND parameter_2 like 'cucurigu AND \picaso' AND parameter_3 IS NULL
```

And I want to make a preg_split() after every AND which is not inside apostrophes. The output of $matches should be an array with

```
0 => parameter_1 >= '23'
1 => parameter_2 like 'cucurigu AND \picaso'
2 => parameter_3 IS NULL
```

I don't know how to use it. I'm sure there is a simple solution to accomplish this with preg_split(). Unfortunately explode() can't do what I need. 
At the moment I have an enormous code which goes char by char and splits the string into an array like the one above. I need to update this big code to a small one because my task often changes.

P.S. If someone is willing to help me, add an explanation of the $pattern.

Comment: Assuming you don't have escaped quotes: `'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s*AND\s*`. This doens't handle double quotes. You might want to clarify your question about above two cases...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are, you can use the skip/fail PCRE trick, and only capture `AND` outside the single quotation marks:

```
'[^']*?'(*SKIP)(*F)|AND
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bC5bA1/2)

The [result](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRk5VbXZQMS1PZFk):

```
Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [0] => parameter_1 >= '23'                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    [1] =>  parameter_2 like 'cucurigu AND \picaso'                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    [2] =>  parameter_3 IS NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
)
```

**Explanation**:
We skip everything what is inside single quotes with `'[^']*?'(*SKIP)(*F)`, and match `AND` in all contexts.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also tell me a short explanation?

Comment: @besciualex: I added a short explanation.

Comment: Also thanks for demo link. Very useful for testing and learning.

Comment: Here you can find more on this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex

Comment: Sorry to disturb. I have a small issue and I can't fix it. Uhm... if the AND does not have any space between it and other values, it doesn't break. I added \A \Z modifiers and it don't work. https://regex101.com/r/kB3xJ4/1

Comment: Ok, then remove the word boundaries: `'[^']*?'(*SKIP)(*F)|AND`.

Comment: wow! :D I tried a lot of things (), \A \Z, etc.. but never thought about removing them completely.